# Unable to access Azure Data lake gen 2 storage for downloading the csv file via c# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am getting the 3 Exceptions below when downloading a `.csv` file from Azure Data lake storage gen 2

```
---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11004): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
```

Here it is the code I written to download the file

```cs
public static string[] downloadContentsFromBlob(string blobAccountName, string blobAccountKey, string containerName, string blobFileName, string blobStoragePath)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Inside download contents from Blob()");

       //string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "TestData/Downloads/");

       string connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + blobAccountName + ";AccountKey=" + blobAccountKey + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

       // Setup the connection to the storage account

       CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

       // Connect to the blob storage

       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

       // Connect to the blob container

       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference($"{containerName}");

       // Connect to the blob file

       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{blobStoragePath + blobFileName}");


       // provide the file download location below            
       string contents = blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;

       Console.WriteLine("Contents from Blob has been Downloaded!");

       return ConvertStringToStringArray(contents);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did tried to repro the issues and with the wrong access key i get 403 and with the incorrect path I  get 404 . I think you may you are not using the right  package .
For me the above code just worked fine with the below nuget package.

```
"Azure.Storage.Blobs" version="12.14.1"
"WindowsAzure.Storage" version="9.3.3"
and I am running .NET 4.72
```

Just wanted to let you know that if you are using
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob , its deprecated .

[image]